# How to I get all files from a directory with a variable extension of specified length?

Tags: c#, file, directory, getfiles, getdirectories

I have a huge directory I need retrieve files from including subdirectories.

I have files that are folders contain various files but I am only interested in specific proprietary files named with an extension with a length of 7 digits.

For example, I have folder that contains the following files:

```
abc.txt
def.txt
GIWFJ1XA.0201000
GIWFJ1UC.0501000
NOOBO0XA.0100100
summary.pdf
someinfo.zip
T7F4JUXA.0300600
vxy98796.csv
YJHLPLBO.0302300
YJHLPLUC.0302800
```

I have tried the following:

```cs
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(someDir, "*.???????", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

and also

```cs
string searchSting = string.Empty;
for (int j = 0; j < 9999999; j++)
{
  searchSting += string.Format(", *.{0} ", j.ToString("0000000"));
}

var fileList2 = Directory.GetFiles(someDir, searchSting, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

which errors because the string is too long obviously.

I want to only return the files with the specified length of the extension, in this case, 7 digits to avoid having to loop over the thousands I would have to process.

I have considered creating a variable string for the search criteria that would contain all 99,999,999 possible digits but d

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I vote to undelete your answer; it provides a Regex alternative and OP already knows how to make GetFiles search all directories with the third argument

Comment: The main point of Xiang's answer was effectively to do `Regex r = new Regex(@"\.\d{7}$");` and `GetFiles(...).Where(r.IsMatch)` - I'd use EnumerateFiles but this Regex is "ends with a dot and 7 digits" which is a compact alternative too

Comment: oof I didn't know GetFiles can do subfolder searching. But I think @DiplomacyNotWar's answer is ideal enough because it doesn't use regex. Still, I revived it for future references. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way you can do this without looping through the files in the directory and its subfolders. The search pattern for `GetFiles` doesn't support regular expressions, so we can't really use something like `[\d]{7}` as a filter. I would suggest using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and then return the files that match your criteria.

You can use this to enumerate the files:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<string> GetProprietaryFiles(string topDirectory)
{
    Func<string, bool> filter = f =>
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(f);
        // is 8 characters long including the .
        // all remaining characters are digits
        return extension.Length == 8 && extension.Skip(1).All(char.IsDigit);
    };

    // EnumerateFiles allows us to step through the files without
    // loading all of the filenames into memory at once.
    IEnumerable<string> matchingFiles =
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(topDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(filter);
                    
    // Return each file as the enumerable is iterated
    foreach (var file in matchingFiles)
    {
        yield return file;
    }
}
```

`Path.GetExtension` includes the `.` so we check that the number of characters including the `.` is 8, and that all remaining characters are digits.

Usage:

```cs
List<string> fileList = GetProprietaryFiles(someDir).ToList();
```

Comment: Note for OP, you could also just take the middle statement and put it wherever you wanted to use, eg `foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Select(Path.GetExtension).Where(e => e.Length == 8 && e.Skip(1).All(Char.IsDigit)))`. Also, side note, these extensions could parse as doubles for an alternative to skip/all

Comment: or maybe because you originally tried a filter of `.???????` you don't even have to test them for being digits

Comment: I know the extensions are all digits and 7 in length (at least for the time being).  They will always be longer than the "standard" 3 or 4.  That was why I tried the obvious of the questions marks.  I am just trying reduce the size of the array/list returned I am looping over.

Answer (score 0):

I would just grab the list of files in the directory, and then check if the substring length after the '.' is equal to 7. (* As long as you know no other files would have that length extension)

**EDITED to use Path instead:**

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp").Where(
    fileName => Path.GetExtension(fileName).Length == 8
    ).ToList();
```

**OLD:**

```
Directory.GetFiles(someDir).Where(
         fileName => fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).Length == 7
).ToList();
```

Comment: This would return files like "ABCDEFG" (without extension) as false positives.

Comment: Yea true, I guess it really depends on their use case for the directory whether or not they need additional cases covered

Comment: Don't use string manipulations to work with paths. Use Path class instead

Comment: Good point, definitely safer

Answer (score 0):

Consider `files` as `Directory.GetFiles()` result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>()
        {"abc.txt", "def.txt", "GIWFJ1XA.0201000", "GIWFJ1UC.0501000", "NOOBO0XA.0100100", "summary.pdf", "someinfo.zip", "T7F4JUXA.0300600", "vxy98796.csv", "YJHLPLBO.0302300", "YJHLPLUC.0302800"};
        Regex r = new Regex("^\\.\\d{7}$");
        foreach (string file in files.Where(o => r.IsMatch(Path.GetExtension(o))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
GIWFJ1XA.0201000
GIWFJ1UC.0501000
NOOBO0XA.0100100
T7F4JUXA.0300600
YJHLPLBO.0302300
YJHLPLUC.0302800
```

Edit: I tried `(r.IsMatch)` instead of using `o` but dotnetfiddle Compiler is giving me error saying

```
Compilation error (line 14, col 27): The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<string>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,bool>)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<string>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,int,bool>)'
```

Can't debug it since I am busy now, I'd be happy if anyone passing by suggest any fix for that. But the current code above works.